# Spreadsheet size % - axlsx - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I am using axlsx to generate excel sheets currently.

I would like to generate the sheet such that when the user opens it, it should open at 80% size by default.

Is there a way to achieve this? I tried looking into the axlsx documentation but I don't think this topic is covered there.

Comment: You should open an issue on the github repository instead of here, you'll be more likely to get an answer

Comment: @GrahamSlick - Thanks much for your suggestion - I just opened https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/609 for this. Thanks again!

Comment: @GrahamSlick - sorry - the link I sent above was for the issue where auto width of columns does not work.

For default zoom size, looks like this link offers a solution - https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/369  

I will try this out and let everyone know if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is available on the GitHub issues page - https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/369

I tried this solution and it works perfectly for me!